# Why the turret is not rotating when detecting the player in specific range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is script i also attached it to a spotlight and the spotlight rotate and light the player when the player is moving between waypoints.

But when i attach also the script to a turret i have the turret is rotating like 180 degrees then stop and never keep rotating tracking the player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateSpotlight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public float smooth = 1f;
    public float rangeSqr;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    Quaternion originalRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target.transform.position.x < transform.position.x + rangeSqr)
        {
            var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.transform.position - transform.position);
            var str = Mathf.Min(rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 1);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, str);
        }
        else
        {
            var str = Mathf.Min(rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 1);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, originalRotation, str);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Turret]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @roelofs Why the turret is not keep rotating facing the player. The player is moving between waypoints but the turret not tracking it.  But if the script is attached for example to spotlight the spotlight will keep tracking the player when the player is inside the range.

Comment: So what does the turret code look like? I think this is way too little information to work with.

Comment: @roelofs In my question i added the script this is the script attached to the turret. For a test i created a turret of my own from sphere and cube and it's rotating fine. I just wonder what could be wrong with this turret.

Answer (score 0):

It's better and more responsive to use VectorX.Distance() than compare pos x and pos y.
I'm pretty sure than your problem come from Quaternion.LookRotation, this function don't give to you the value you espected.
Personally I use this for angle calculation :

```
    Vector3 a = targetPos - _transform.position;
    Vector3 b = Vector3.forward;
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(a, b);
    float finalAngle = (Vector3.Cross(a, b).y > 0 ? -angle : angle);
```

You can take a look to the "complet" code

```
private void Update()
{
    //check range
    if (Vector3.Distance(targetPos, turretPos) < maxRange)
        AutoAttack(targetPos);
}
public override void AutoAttack(Vector3 targetPos)
{
    Vector3 a = targetPos - _transform.position;
    Vector3 b = Vector3.forward;
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(a, b);
    Rotation(Vector3.Cross(a, b).y > 0 ? -angle : angle);

    //this condition is to to fire only when the turret is currently looking at target
    if (Mathf.Abs(Mathf.DeltaAngle(_transform.eulerAngles.y, (Vector3.Cross(a, b).y > 0 ? -angle : angle))) < minAngleToFire)
        Attacking();
}
//call to rotate the in y axis
public void RotationY(float angle)
{
    _transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
}
```